# margin in WPF Usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, styles, margin

```
<Style x:Key="MyControl" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource PathA}"/>
                    <Path Margin="8" Style="{StaticResource PathB}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this `usercontrol` style, I put a `path` behind another `path`, which has a `margin` of 8.

Everthing goes fine if I create a `usercontrol` with `height`/`width` large enough.

Problem is, the `PathB` would be shrunk out of sight if the size is near or below 8.

I know it's the `margin` which pushed `PathB`. Isn't `margin` a relative value in a `usercontrol`? How can I handle this if I want to keep a little space between `PathA` and `PathB` even when resizing?

[image: size large enough]

[image: size small enough]

In the second pic the orange pie is missing because it's shrunk by the margin.

Comment: could you post some screens or what you see and what you expect?

Comment: @pushpraj I updated desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may perhaps define a minimum width and height to the grid or path or even user control.

```
<Style x:Key="MyControl" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid MinWidth="12" MinHeight="12">
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource PathA}"/>
                    <Path Margin="8" Style="{StaticResource PathB}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

or perhaps use a ViewBox here

```
<Style x:Key="MyControl" TargetType="UserControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Viewbox>
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Style="{StaticResource PathA}"/>
                        <Path Margin="8" Style="{StaticResource PathB}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ViewBox will keep the proportion intact while re-sizing the content